# frost proof spigot

Tags: plumbing

My outdoor frost proof spigot worked fine before winter.
I detached the water hose before winter.
After the winter, the spigot does not work, nor does it leak, inside or outside.
Do I need to replace it, or is there a repair I can do.
Thanks

Comment: Does the handle turn with the normal amount of force, or has it become very easy or very stiff?

Answer (score 1):

The washer that seals the water flow may have become unscrewed from the end of the shaft. I had this problem. I had to remove the shaft and tighten the washer back on the end

Answer (score 0):

It may just be the handle or if it's not turning then the seal may be stuck. These do want to be tilted down a little when installed, so they can drain out. But, if it's not actually blown apart by ice, then these are usually re-buildable. See example below. If the outer sleeve is split, you'll have to get a new spigot.

[image: sillcock]